# How to set ForkJoinPool with the desired number of worker threads in CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier) method?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, forkjoinpool

According to Oracle,

> **static  CompletableFuture supplyAsync(Supplier supplier)**
> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a
> task running in the **ForkJoinPool.commonPool()** with the value obtained
> by calling the given Supplier.
>
> **static  CompletableFuture supplyAsync(Supplier supplier, Executor
> executor)** Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously
> completed by a task running in the given executor with the value
> obtained by calling the given Supplier.

If I use **"static  CompletableFuture supplyAsync(Supplier supplier)"** method , it by default use **ForkJoinPool.commonPool()**. This returns a ForkJoinPool which has the number of worker threads equal to the number of available cores in the running machine.

But, I want to use a ForkJoinPool with my custom number of worker threads. Using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() I cannot do that.

So how can I use **CompletableFuture.supplyAsync** method with my declared ForkJoinPool using the number of worker thread that I want?

Comment: One more alternative :   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(yourSupplier,
                             Executors.newWorkStealingPool(Your_thread_Acount));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) implements `Executor`.

Therefore, you can write your code like this:

```
int threadCount = 3;
ForkJoinPool myPool = new ForkJoinPool(threadCount);
CompletableFuture cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(mySup, myPool);
```

Comment: threadCount passed is not to set the number of worker thread. It is for desired level of parallelism.